# Htaccess Rewrite Rule to have a Friendly URL

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm using godaddy hosting and my domain is pointed to the directory named "abc"
I created a directory "temp" under "abc" directory and placed an .htaccess file under "temp" directory.

I want to rewrite url as follow

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/temp/VARIABLE_VALUE/VARIABLE_FILENAME.php?id=12&c=usa
```

to

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/temp/VARIABLE_FILENAME.php?var=VARIABLE_VALUE&id=12&c=usa
```

my .htaccess file consists of the following code.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^-]*)$ /temp/index.php?var=$1 [L]
```

But, it gives me 404 error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this rule in

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /temp/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^.]+\.php)$ $2?var=$1 [L,QSA]
```